# Do you go through immigration during a layover in Medellín on the way to Bogota?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, layovers, colombia, medellin

We have a flight on a US carrier that has a layover  in Medellín (Colombia) with a separate leg from Medellín to Bogotá, which is handled by a local carrier. The ticket itself is for a flight from a US city to Bogotá with layover in Medellín of a few hours. We were wondering if the layover means that we also retrieve our checked-in luggage and go through customs/immigration in Medellín.

Will we be able to retrieve our luggage, go through immigration and then exit the airport in Medellín?

Comment: Did you do the trip already?

Comment: @aris any update? Are you able to answer your own question now?

Comment: I did the trip but I can't say that my experience will be the same for everybody on every airline. I asked airline (American) and airport employees various times during the trip and received a different answer every time. It was a very confusing experience but in the end yes, I went through migration in Medellín and retrieved my luggage and exited the airport.

Answer (score 2):

OP commented on the experience:

> I did the trip but I can't say that my experience will be the same for everybody on every airline. I asked airline (American) and airport employees various times during the trip and received a different answer every time. It was a very confusing experience but in the end yes, I went through migration in Medellín and retrieved my luggage and exited the airport.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all airports in Colombia have two arrival terminals, one for domestic, and other for international flights. If your flight has a layover, you must go through immigration/customs, but your luggage will go to the destination airport